# Is there an issue with the Steam Store right now?

Tags: steam

I'm currently in the Steam Store and it seems like the language keeps changing, and/or I keep being logged in/out and/or it keeps thinking that I'm another account.

Is anybody else experiencing the same issues right now? I don't think it's Christmas traffic, since the Store still loads fine.

I'm suspecting that maybe some hackers are messing around with the servers during its high traffic in an attempt to gain access to accounts with saved credentials in order to gift purchases or game items.

Some rudimentary Google searches are making references to DDoS attacks (expected), but those don't result in these sorts of effects; only server downtime at best.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with a temporary outage/disruption in the ordinary function of a website.

Answer (score 2):

You're not the only one — there *is* a major issue with the store.

What is wrong is unclear right now. Assuming you don't get a blank page with an *Error Code: −302 (Unable to load URL, bad hostname or format)*, the store is misbehaving. It appears to be a problem with login sessions and profile: shopping carts are filled with the wrong items, being logged into the Steam client doesn't log you into the Store view, viewing your account details shows someone else's profile information (which is a massive data breach problem), and store display language keeps changing (which is probably related to the profile issues).

The Steam Discussions forum's front page is full of people wigging out about it, so you're definitely not the only one:

[image: Screenshot of Steam Discussion forum 1st page, where every thread is about login/profile/store/language issues]

Steam should probably be avoided like digital plague today. I expect Valve is going to have a lot of fallout from today.

Comment: I noticed that the store wasn't recognizing that I was logged in using the Steam client.

Comment: Whup, just through the Steam client I see that the Storefront is suddenly in Russian... and now I tried again and it's back to English, but I'm somehow logged out from there even though the client. Something's up.

Comment: I reported the issue to valve directly.

Comment: Valve is now aware of this issue. http://ardao.me/files/qxm.png

Comment: It is now ok on my end

Comment: @ardaozkal Valve appears to have *just now* terminated every Store session cookie. That probably doesn't fix it though, just helps minimise the damage until the issue can be fixed.

Comment: Steam Discussions isn't even loading for me, so I can't check there. That's probably due to all of the (concerned) traffic. @ardaozkal: Who is Son of Thor?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie well, that only caused me to see more info about people. Bad move. [also for the sake of it crowd, valve atm](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KH_0uybs93I/hqdefault.jpg)

Comment: @CakePrincess Valve employee who takes care of translations. I contacted him b/c I had him added.